# Change default naming pattern when importing geopackage

Tags: qgis

When importing geopackages into QGIS (i.e. by dragging the GPKG into QGIS), the default name for all layers to be imported – if the *Add layers to a group* option is not selected – is `[name_gpkg] – [name_layer_in_gpkg]`.

Is there a way to modify the default naming pattern when importing geopackages into QGIS?